# Using Cytoscape with a form in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this **HTML**:

```
<form>
    Text :<br>
    <input type="text" name="nameid" id="nameid" value="">
    <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
<br />

<div id="cy"></div>
```

And this **JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "/MyController/MyAction2",
            data: { nameid: $('#nameid').val() },
            success: function (newdata) {
                var cy = cytoscape({
                    container: document.getElementById("cy"),
                    elements: JSON.parse(newdata)

                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this **style** :

```
<style>
    #cy {
        width: 80%;
        height: 80%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

When I make `position` `absolute`, I can see the graph but the buttons and textbox become unclickable, when I make `position` `center` or `fixed`, textbox and buttons become clickable but then I can't see the graph. How can I see both of them? Thanks.

Comment: apply  [**`z-index`**](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjD7seX3tDTAhXErI8KHf9UADwQFgguMAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fcssref%2Fpr_pos_z-index.asp&usg=AFQjCNF46nDdL-BPAvRgQpmYSPpGCwY2GQ&sig2=TSxbCwOuX41PS2_z6oMXQA) rule in your css..

Comment: `position: center` isn't a thing

Comment: Why do you want to define `position` as `absolute` or `fixed`? Why not delete `position`, `top` and `left` in the CSS?